# Control variables SPSS Mediation PROCESS (by Hayes)

Tags: variables, process, spss, mediator

I have run my analysis in PROCESS looking at the total effect and indirect effect to establish a direct relation between `(x-y)` and mediated relation between `x-y` through `M` (compound path `a` and `b`). However I now also need to include control variables; age, gender, job tenure, education and length of employment, but am unsure how to go about this. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)